# Can I use ReactJS or Angular to create multi-page web applications?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, react-router, single-page-application, ngroute

I am a little bit confused about front end frameworks. I read that if you used `ng-route` or `react-router` it would make your app a single page application, so does it mean if I don't use `ng-route/react-router` and instead used express for server rendering would the app still considered a `SPA` ?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your final question, if you're serving bits of your site from different Express routes, then by the definition of a Single Page Application it's not a SPA anymore, no.

However, there's nothing explicitly wrong with doing that. ReactJs is a tool and a way of working with components. If you want to work with components, but you're more comfortable with serving your individual views from different server-side routes then just do that. Not everything needs to be a SPA. Once you're comfortable with the core of how React works from a mark-up/component point of view, you can start incorporating partial page renders and client-side routing etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not getting the point about SPA. Please read the following:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application